# How to find the distance between two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames, the first one:

```
first <- rnorm(3)
second <- rnorm(3)
third <- rnorm (3)

MainNumbers = data.frame(first,second,third)
```

And the second one:

```
Operator1= rnorm(50)
Operator2= rnorm(50)

MainOperator= data.frame(Operator1,Operator2)
```

And by using the Euclidean distance :

```
euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
```

I would like to see if its possible to do this:

1. Every value in a row in MainNumbers should be the `x1` value in `euc.dist`
2. Every value in a row in MainOperator should be the `x2` value in `euc.dist`
3. For each value in `x1` calculate every  `euc.dist` with each value in `x2`. There
   are less values in MainNumbers and more in MainOperator. That means I should take
   the first row of the MainNumbers as `x1` and every value in MainOperator as `x2`. The 
    result should be a column made only by the calculation of the first row of
    MainNumbers and  every number in MainOperator. The second column should be the
    result of the calculation of the second row of MainNumbers as the `x1` and
    as the `x2` every value in the MainOperator. 
    The same for the third row and every value in MainOperator.
4. The final result should be a data frame with 3 columns so that the columns should be 
    filled with values from the `euc. dist` from two data frames, where each columns is
    a result of the one row of MainNumbers and every value of MainOperator.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Here are my attempts to solve this:

I have a vague idea how to solve this and this is the pseudoce I had in mind:

```
define empty data frame
for each i in row(MainNumbers) use as x1 
for j in row(Mainoperator) use as x2
calculate euc. dist 
save it in a empty data  frame as column
repeat for each i rown(MainNumbers)
```

Thus far I am stuck with the for loops and how to put every values in x1 and to calculate
the euc. dist. with every other  value in the second data frame. I use this code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(MainNumbers)) {

  x=as.numeric(as.vector(MainNumbers[i,]))

}
```

With this I can get that the firs row is a numeric vector, and then I can use it as a variable in the eust. dist. formula. But I do not know how to take every row and use it
as a seperate numeric vector. I am not really good with complicated for loops, to be honest.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik
I know that I have to use a for loop or an apply function. I do not know how to do that. I cannot really understand how to take each value of first data frame and use every other value in the second data frame. I am confused about how it should look in the for loop. Should I use two for loops for every data frame?

I have a vague idea how the psedocode should look like:

`define empty data frame; for each i in row(MainNumbers) use as x1
 ;for j in row(Mainoperator) use as x2; calculate euc. dist ;save it in a empty data frame;repeat for each i `

Comment: Document your attempts in the main question (hit edit on the lower left side of the question).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik
I made my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself:

```
apply(MainOperator,1,function(MainOperator) (apply(MainNumbers,1,function(MainNumbers,MainOperator)dist(rbind(MainNumbers,MainOperator)),MainOperator)))
```