# Closest points from another dataset within a certain direction

Tags: r, geometry

I have roughly 1000 points in one dataset "df1" which have coordinates scattered across the coordinate system. In another dataset "df2", I have 27 points placed across the coordinate system.

For each point in df1, I want to estimate the closest distance to a point in df2, located within the direction of 165-225° (in relation to the unit circle).

How can this be done in R?

If the direction did not matter, then I could solve the problem with the approach from [Finding closest point from other data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211948/finding-closest-point-from-other-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This answer suggest to define your two dataset as data tables and then use the following function:

```
    dist <- function(a, b){
            dt <- data.table((df2$x-a)^2+(df2$y-b)^2)
            return(which.min(dt$V1))}
 results <- df1[, j = list(Closest =  dist(x, y)), by = 1:nrow(df1)]
```

However, I am unsure how to combine this with the direction criteria.

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Ditlev

Comment: If I understand your question  correctly it seems like some basic Pythagorean geometry (a^2 + b^2 = c^2) will get you started as √(((Xdf1 - Xdf2)^2)+((Ydf1 - Ydf2)^2)) will give you the distances between your points, and then subset those falling within the arc somehow, then subset the minimum values, as an order of operations? Don't have a more detailed specific solution for you. Maybe you could provide some example data? *This also depends on the co-ordinates system units you are working with, for example UTM will work as 1x = 1y = 1 metre.

Comment: The coordinates that I am working with is just  (x,y) (-100;100,-100;100) m so I am not really using any specific type of coordinates. I am aware of the formulaes that will calculate the distances from one point to another point and also the formulaes for calculating the degree slope of a line, but I am lacking the programming skills to combine this technically in a smart way in R only for the shortest distance and for points in different data frames.

Comment: If I am right, this constraint breaks the distance relation, and all the Voronoi machinery falls apart. I wonder if you can do much better than exhaustive comparisons. I you don't care about efficiency, first select the points of df2 located in the desired sector and find the closest distance.

Comment: Thank you @YvesDaoust. Is it still impossible even though the points in df2 are located in a specific pattern?

Comment: Is what impossible ?

Comment: To make a coding that determines which point in df2 that is closest to each point in df1 when the points in df2 are not just distributed randomly but are located in a pattern.